# Validation of nested directives in angular 1.2.16

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel

Background:

Let's say I want a directive that edits and validates text. We'll consider a unit value for simplicity's sake. So I create a directive that binds to a value in the model.

In this simple example, the directive validates false if the input is not in the form [NUMBER][IDENTIFIER] or if the value of any of it's sub-directives validates to false.

Whenever the text changes, the directive splits it into two variables. The directive's template has two sub-directives, one for each of the two variables. Each sub-directive is bound through ng-model. Each sub-directive validates each value as the input changes. For example, if the [IDENTIFIER] sub-directive expects 'px' or 'in', it validates false for any other value. If either of the two sub-directives validate to false, the main directive also validates to false.

I want to take this sort of approach in designing ng-model based editors for more complex text patterns while taking advantage of the existing validation mechanisms in ng-model.

Questions:

Can you read the validity of a directive's children as part of determining whether the model is valid?

If ng-model takes an object rather than a string, can validation be triggered when any changes occur to the model?

Answer (score 0):

I qualify these answers by saying I'm an angular newby....

First question. 
Yes I think if you had a directive that adds a validator to the validation chain there is no reason that it could not walk it's children and check their validity. The parent may have to have a hidden input to attach the ngModelController to which would then check the visible children.

Second question.
Of course. What the model contains is irrelevant. The validation will run if the model contents are changed.